# hexagon-sim WARNING: DRIL in dril.cpp:6843: Unable to load symbols from exe file

Tags: clang, llvm, qualcomm, hexagonal-architecture, hexagon-dsp

Can you tell me how to solve it?

"hexagon-sim INFO: The rev_id used in the simulation is 0x00004060 (v60a_512)
hexagon-sim WARNING: uiLoadElfSymfile in dril.cpp:5902: Cannot find string table in ELF file
hexagon-sim WARNING: DRIL in dril.cpp:6843: Unable to load symbols from exe file "

Comment: Can you share how you invoked and built the program you're trying to execute?